# Json.net, deserialize dates out of range

Tags: c#, postgresql, json.net

I'm having trouble deserializing dates with Newtonsoft.Json.

I have a class in C#, and complex data types in postgresql. With the row_to_json function of postgresql I have lot of the work done retriving data from database.

Everything works fine, then, when I have an infinity date, I got this error:

```
{"Could not convert string to DateTime: -infinity. Path 'valid_from', line 1, position 101."}
```

The code line I use is:

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(l[icont], myclass);
```

Where l is a list of json strings, icont is a counter and myclass is an instance of my class.

The closest documentation I found to my problem is here, where this problem is considered a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22955

I have few workarounds in mind:

- Use strings for dates in my c# class. I don't like this :-/
- Force the postgresql function to return special dates, like 01/01/1800 and 01/01/2200 and manage them. This can be OK because it is not storical data, but it is not... elegant.

How can I workaround this and keep infinity values in db?

Comment: There is not an "-Infinity" date in C#. You have to map it to DateTime.MinValue or - changing property type to DateTime? - to null.

Comment: I think I must go for null :-/

Comment: Also Min Value works and you do not need any extra check for null...